# How to apply 'load_from' and 'dump_to' to every field in a marshmallow schema?

Tags: python, marshmallow

I've been trying to implement an 'abstract' schema class that will automatically convert values in CamelCase (serialized) to snake_case (deserialized).

```
class CamelCaseSchema(marshmallow.Schema):
    @marshmallow.pre_load
    def camel_to_snake(self, data):
        return {
            utils.CaseConverter.camel_to_snake(key): value for key, value in data.items()
        }

    @marshmallow.post_dump
    def snake_to_camel(self, data):
        return {
            utils.CaseConverter.snake_to_camel(key): value for key, value in data.items()
        }
```

While using something like this works nicely, it does not achieve everything applying `load_from` and `dump_to` to a field does. Namely, it fails to provide correct field names when there's an issue with deserialization. For instance, I get: 
`{'something_id': [u'Not a valid integer.']}` instead of `{'somethingId': [u'Not a valid integer.']}`.

While I can post-process these emitted errors, this seems like an unnecessary coupling that I wish to avoid if I'm to make the use of schema fully transparent.

Any ideas? I tried tackling the metaclasses involved, but the complexity was a bit overwhelming and everything seemed exceptionally ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using marshmallow 2. Marshmallow 3 is now out and I recommend using it. My answer will apply to marshmallow 3.

In marshmallow 3, `load_from` / `dump_to` have been replace by a single attribute : `data_key`.

You'd need to alter `data_key` in each field when instantiating the schema. This will happen after field instantiation but I don't think it matters.

You want to do that ASAP when the schema is instantiated to avoid inconsistency issues. The right moment to do that would be in the middle of `Schema._init_fields`, before the `data_key` attributes are checked for consistency. But duplicating this method would be a pity. Besides, due to the nature of the camel/snake case conversion the consistency checks can be applied before the conversion anyway.

And since `_init_fields` is private API, I'd recommend doing the modification at the end of `__init__`.

```
class CamelCaseSchema(Schema):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            fields.data_key = utils.CaseConverter.snake_to_camel(field_name)
```

I didn't try that but I think it should work.

Comment: While do I agree that switching to marshmallow 3 is desirable, it's not possible under my current circumstances. For anyone else stuck with version 2, setting `load_from` and `dump_to` works just as well. Thank you for the thoughtful response, the solution seems to work perfectly!